# Different back colors for the `LaTeX` code and its output

Tags: formatting, tcolorbox

In the following code, is there a way to have different back colors for the `LaTeX` code and its output?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\newtcblisting{doclatex}{
    colback = black!15, % For the code only?
%   ? = white,          % For the output.
}

\begin{document}

\begin{doclatex}
$just + A = test$
\end{doclatex}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example (you need the `skin` library):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\newtcblisting{doclatex}{
    skin=bicolor,
    colbacklower = white,          % For the output.
    colback = black!15, % For the code only?
}

\begin{document}

\begin{doclatex}
$just + A = test$
\end{doclatex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Source: page 229 of the `tcolorbox` manual).

Comment: What I have missed is the use of `bicolor`. :-o

Comment: ;-) I suspected it (and the `[most]`, although probably can be trimmed down...)